# jetty scanner NullPointerException

Tags: jetty

every buddy:
i'm so confused when i see this exception about jetty.

```
Exception in thread "Scanner-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFile(Scanner.java:576)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFiles(Scanner.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:348)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Exception in thread "Scanner-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFile(Scanner.java:576)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFiles(Scanner.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:348)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

and the source code about Scanner.java is:

```
// If it is a directory, scan if it is a known directory or the depth is OK.
    573            if (f.isDirectory() && (depth<_scanDepth || _scanDepth==-1 ||        
    _scanDirs.contains(f)))
    574            {
    575                File[] files = f.listFiles();
    576                for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    577                    scanFile(files[i], scanInfoMap,depth+1);
    578            }
    579        }
```

how line 576 code occurs nullpointer exception?

jetty-version: 8.1.3.v20120416

need your guys help, 3q so mush.

Answer (score 0):

On line 576, `files` is null, which implies `f` is null.

Please check if `f` is successfully instantiated.

Comment: Are you saying `f` is a directory that actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this very same error recently. What I did was to set OS limit on the max number of files opened.

This can be set in /etc/security/limits.conf by adding the following lines:

```
* soft nofile 65536
* hard nofile 65536
```

and then rebooting the server.

The * means that this setting applies to all users. You can put in the specific user that you use to run the Jetty process. The value 65536 specifies the maximum number of files (nofile) that can be opened. The specifics of this setting can be found by looking at the limits.conf man page.